# Angular single-page-app behind authentication

Tags: angularjs

Hi I am new in Angular an I need help.

I want to create single-page-app.

Basic info:

- navigate via url
- whole app is behind authentication (if not authorized only login page show, maybe, reset password, contact page, etc... -> i will select urls which is not under authorization)
- behind authentication is static layout like header, menu, side bars, footer and container for content (ng-view)

please help me with it (html structure, templates, controllers, directives, etc...)

my idea of structure
pages:

- index.html
- login-template.html
- layout-template.html
- menu-template.html
- content1.html
- content2.html
- content3.html
- content4.html
- list-of-items-template.html

I don't know what must be in index page, but in layout-template.html will be some static html, some templates like menu-template.html and ng-view where content will be shown by URL.

Within some template will be another template like template for list of items with controller for this list template

I want controllers for each template, like: (loginCtrl, layoutCtrl, menuCtrl, content1Ctrl)

I hope that makes sense

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am an Angular newbie like you and chose to go for Yeoman Angular generator as it is really handy for taking care of the file structures and makes all the needed boilerplate, unit test environments etc. So, basically check it out on http://yeoman.io and do the tutorial from there. Then start your own project, and create the views with the angular sub generator, like this:

Fist make your app basic structure:

```
yo angular
```

Then add the views with the route using sub-generator (details on angular generator can be found from https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular)

```
yo angular:route your_view
...
```

At least I use the index.html for defining the static layout for the whole app, and then I have the views "in the middle part" of the page like angular generator default example does using views in separate HTML files generated by "yo" -command. I don't need (yet) the SASS but I am just fine with bootstrap css. And finally, to keep HTML files nice and clean, I have found ng-include directive very handy, e.g. if using HTML tabs and having each tab content in its own separate HTML file.

Authentication is done in the backend side, where web server does static redirect to login page when user is not authenticated, and to my index page when there is valid authorisation in place.

I am sure there are many other ways to do this, but this is how I did it. It works nice and seems to be quite handy in maintenance too...